# Regex to find a word and replace with a line containing the word in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file where each line is a word.

```
Abc_123
Def_345
```

I want to replace each line such as the word is inserted in the middle like this:

```
'1' NULL, 'test' 'Abc_123', 'reg'
'1' NULL, 'test' 'Def_345', 'reg'
```

I know ^ and $ can be used to insert at the start and beginning. But how do I insert in the middle ? 
Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `^\w+$` and replace with `'1' NULL, 'test' '$0', 'reg'`

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `^\w+$`
**Replace With**: `'1' NULL, 'test' '$0', 'reg'`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDuiW7/1)

[image]